# Getting incorrect output when using the Java method indexof in combination with substring to create a new string

Tags: java, string, split, substring, indexof

In my program I am trying to split a string at the "," character. After I split the string, I need to create a new string after the "=" character. Then I need to rebuild the string back to its original state. Currently I'm able to split the string and rebuild it to its original state. However when I try to create a new string using the indexof and substring methods, I'm not getting the correct string. I have listed my code below along with my current output and my disired output. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
public class StringTestProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) {

String relativeDN = "cn=abc,dn=xyz,ou=abc/def";
System.out.println(relativeDN);

//Split String
String[] stringData = relativeDN.split(",");


{
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
CharSequence charAdded = ",";

// loop thru each element of the array
for (int place = 0; place < stringData.length; place++) {
System.out.println(stringData[place]);

{

int eq = relativeDN.indexOf('=');
String sub = relativeDN.substring(0, eq);           
System.out.println(sub);

}


// append element to the StringBuilder
sb.append(stringData[place]);

// avoids adding an extra ',' at the end
if (place < stringData.length - 1)

// if not at the last element, add the ',' character
sb.append(charAdded);

}

System.out.print(sb.toString());

}
}
}
```

My original string `"cn=abc,dn=xyz,ou=abc/def"`

My current output:

```
cn=abc (split string)
cn (create new String)
dn=xyz (split string)
cn (create new String)
ou=abc/def (split string)
cn (create new String)
cn=abc,dn=xyz,ou=abc/def (rebuild String to its original form)
```

My desired output:

```
cn=abc (split string)
abc (create new string)
dn=xyz (split string)
xyz (create new String)
ou=abc/def (split string)
abc/def (create new String)
cn=abc,dn=xyz,ou=abc/def (rebuild String to its original form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following lines:

`int eq = relativeDN.indexOf('=');
 String sub = relativeDN.substring(0, eq);` in your `for` loop to

`int eq = stringData[place].indexOf('=');
 String sub = stringData[place].substring(eq+1, stringData[place].length());`

You need the separated strings in each iteration so you will need to use `stringData[place]`. As you were using `relativeDN`, it was taking your original string in every iteration and was returning `cn` for each iteration.

Also for printing the string after `=`, you need to specify the starting location as the location after `=` and end location as `end of string(length)` to `substring` function.

Comment: Prerak thanks for the help and the detailed explanation this line of code solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pattern and Matcher classes.

```
String s = "cn=abc,dn=xyz,ou=abc/def";
String parts[] = s.split(",");
for(String i: parts)
{
    System.out.println(i);
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<==).+").matcher(i);
    while(m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
cn=abc
abc
dn=xyz
xyz
ou=abc/def
abc/def
cn=abc,dn=xyz,ou=abc/def
```

**OR**

Using the StringBuilder class.

```
String relativeDN = "cn=abc,dn=xyz,ou=abc/def";
String[] stringData = relativeDN.split(",");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i =0;i<stringData.length;i++)
    {
        if(i!=0)
        {
            sb.append(",");
        }
System.out.println(stringData[i]);
int eq = stringData[i].indexOf('=');
String sub = stringData[i].substring(eq+1,stringData[i].length());           
System.out.println(sub);
sb.append(stringData[i]);
}
System.out.print(sb.toString());
```

**Output:**

```
cn=abc
abc
dn=xyz
xyz
ou=abc/def
abc/def
cn=abc,dn=xyz,ou=abc/def
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Avinash,however I want to use the mthods indexof and substring to get my desired output.

Comment: you need to use this `substring(eq+1,stringData[i].length());` as substring.

Comment: @Papitulo why restricted to indexof and substring ? is it a homework or an exercise ?

Comment: @niceman it is an exercise, I know it can be done using these methods and I want to learn how instead of abandoning it for an alternative method.

Comment: @Papitulo main part is `substring(eq+1,stringData[i].length());` that's what i said before the answer you accepted.